# How do I access an array in my header file from my implementation file when overloading << operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

If I take out the line where I am outputting the contents of data[], it compiles fine. I seem to be having trouble understanding accessing the array through the implementation file. Any help would be apprecciated.

implementation file function:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& output, const Bag& b1)
     {
        for(int i = 0; i< b1.used; i++)
        {
            output <<Bag.data[i]<<" "; // LINE OF ERROR
        }
        output<<endl;
        return output;
     }
```

header file:

```
#ifndef BAG_H
#define BAG_H
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
namespace greg_bag{
    using namespace std;


    class Bag
    {
    public:
        typedef int value_type;
        typedef std:: size_t size_type;
        static const size_type CAPACITY = 30;

        Bag(){used = 0;}

        void erase();
        bool erase_one(const value_type& target);
        void insert (const value_type& entry);
        //void operator += (const bag& addend);

        //size_type size()const {return used;}
        //size_type count(const value_type& target) const;

        //bag operator +(const bag& b1, const bag& b2);
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Bag&);


    private:

        value_type data[CAPACITY];
        size_type used;

    };
}
#endif
```

error message:
error: expected primary-expression before '.' token|

Comment: It should be `output <<b1.data[i]<<" ";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data is not a static variable so that you can use it directly with class name.
data is different for each instance of a class. Use the following code :

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& output, const Bag& b1)
{
   for(int i = 0; i< b1.used; i++)
   {
       output <<b1.data[i]<<" "; // LINE OF ERROR
   }
output<<endl;
return output;
}
```